# passing args from main app to plugin

Tags: c#, plugins

I need to pass array of strings and int to plugin, but arguments can change during runtime. What's the best solution to achieve that?

Comment: it's very unclear what you want to achieve - got some sample code?

Comment: I just need example of passing some data (string[] and int, etc) from main app to plugin. I tried with CreateInstace.. but I have some trouble and don't even know if it's a idea. Let's say user chooses list of files and int in main app. Then loads plugin which have to display list of files. Of course it's just simple example.

Answer (score 0):

Are you creating an application which has plug-inable components? IE, and application that has an interface where you're going to dynamically activate instances by reference a assembly which abides by some interface?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
(T) Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), param1, param2);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm making a bit of an assumption here, that your plugins all implement a given interface. For example:

```
public interface IPluginComponent
{
    // Example other method - not relevant to this example
    void Start();
    // Example other method - not relevant to this example
    void Stop();
    // Method that is called and passed the data
    void DoWork(object workData);
}
```

You'll note the `DoWork` method that I've listed in the interface. I've provided a, deliberately vague, `object workData` parameter which you could tweak to fit your needs, allowing you to pass whatever data is appropriate into the plugin.

So, what you can do is:

```
// Call a method that returns the appropriate plugin
var pluginToCall = GetPlugin();

// Files that are to be passed to plugin
List<File> files = GetFilesToPassToPlugin();

// Call the plugin and pass the List<File> to it
pluginToCall.DoWork(files);
```